# How do I make custom CSS cursors retina compatible?

Tags: css, retina-display, mouse-cursor

I was wondering how I could use a custom cursor in a webapp on a retina display. I know that normally, an image will be displayed at two times its normal size, due to the scale factor, and in making your site compatible with a retina display, you must take a 2x scale image, and set its in-browser rendering width and height to half its actual dimensions. Since cursors don't have size properties (to my knowledge), how can I ensure that a cursor will be rendered with the highest possible fidelity?

Thanks.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I quite like the generic solution proposed [here](http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/06/make-sure-your-site-looks-good-on-the-new-retina-macbook-pro/), especially the fact that the author remembered to target all browsers that could be run on Macbook Pro with Retina Display.

```
@media only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /*your hi-res cursor styling*/
}
```

I'm quite curious if this would work correctly in Windows when run on the same hardware (with Bootcamp or Parallels etc.)

Comment: How do I know that the browser is going to display the cursor image without scaling it up? That is, how do I know that the cursor won't appear two times larger (in terms of physical size) when the high-res image is used, because the browser is applying a 2x scale factor to the image. Normally, as shown in the example in the link you gave, you'd somehow limit the size of the displayed image, using background-size for example, to force the browser to not apply the 2x scale factor. However, the cursor attribute only takes a url, not a size, so how can I limit the size there?

Comment: @Maz: what have you tried? I was assuming that cursor urls were rendered pixel-per-pixel, resulting in a visually smaller cursor with the same fidelity (unlinke normal images which are interpolated). I can only speculate without having access to a retina display mac.